# Using .WrapWith when creating HtmlTag controls

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, fubumvc

I am creating some HTML Helper methods based on the Fubu project's [HtmlTags library](http://htmltags.fubu-project.org/) for an application based on the inevitable Twitter Bootstrap framework. For most of the simple controls, I have had no problems directly sub-classing HtmlTag; however, when it comes to the more complex controls, which usually need to be nested within a div tag, it gets a little more complex.

For instance, I have a TextboxWidget, which is implemented something like this:

```
public class TextboxWidget : HtmlTag
{
    public TextboxWidget() : base("input")
    {
        Attr("type", "text");
        AddClass("form-control");
        NoClosingTag();
    }
}
```

which is pretty straightforward. It can then be used like this (with a few other extension methods):

```
@Html.Bootstrap().Textbox(m => m.FirstName).Data("bind", "Employee.FirstName")
```

to give the desired result.

My implementation of a DatepickerWidget goes something like this:

```
public class DatepickerWidget : HtmlTag
{
    public DatepickerWidget() : base("input")
    {
        Attr("type", "text");
        Attr("role", "datepicker");
        AddClasses("form-control", "datepicker");
        Data("dateformat", "dd/mm/yy");

        Button = new HtmlTag("span").AddClass("input-group-addon");
        var icon = new HtmlTag("i").AddClass("icon-calendar");

        Button.Append(icon);
        Append(Button);
        WrapWith(new DivTag().AddClass("input-group"));
    }
}
```

which is then used like this:

```
@Html.Bootstrap().Datepicker(m => m.StartDate).DataBind("click", "fnProcessClick").AddClass("special-offer")
```

but for some reason, the wrapping div tag is not being rendered. If I write some unit tests for the control, then I can see the div tag in the object model (in the Parent property), but it just never gets turned into HTML on the page.

I really want to keep the main input element as the focal element of the control, so all the nice HtmlTag extensions hang off the widget; will I have to go down the route [displayed by Jimmy Bogard](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/07/25/conventional-html-in-asp-net-mvc-building-larger-primitives/) by exposing modifiers for each of the individual elements within the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WrapWith` returns a new HtmlTag; in your implementation of `DatePickerWidget` it basically just gets ignored, and the DatePickerWidget is still just the "input" tag you based it on.

One option would be to drop the `WrapWith` line from your class add the wrapper later:

`@Html.Bootstrap().Datepicker(m => m.StartDate).DataBind("click", "fnProcessClick").AddClass("special-offer").WrapWith(new DivTag().AddClass("input-group"))`

If that's cumbersome, you could shorten it by adding a method to the class for it:

```
 public HtmlTag WrapWithInputGroup()
 {
    return WrapWith(new DivTag().AddClass("input-group"));
 }

@Html.Bootstrap().Datepicker(m => m.StartDate).DataBind("click", "fnProcessClick").AddClass("special-offer").WrapWithInputGroup()
```

Another option which works the way you expected your original class to work would be to override `ToString()`:

```
public class DatepickerWidget2 : HtmlTag
{
    public DatepickerWidget2()
        : base("input")
    {
        Attr("type", "text");
        Attr("role", "datepicker");
        AddClasses("form-control", "datepicker");
        Data("dateformat", "dd/mm/yy");

        var Button = new HtmlTag("span").AddClass("input-group-addon");
        var icon = new HtmlTag("i").AddClass("icon-calendar");

        Button.Append(icon);
        Append(Button);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return WrapWith(new DivTag().AddClass("input-group")).ToString();
    }
}
```

Huge, huge caveat: in my quick-and-dirty testing this works, but that might be counter to the original design of HtmlTags. I'd use this solution with caution (until/unless somebody like Jeremy Miller shows up here and says it's the right solution).

Comment: I like the ToString override suggestion - I'll give that a spin and see how it goes. I'd already started down the inline WrapWith approach given in your first example, but that just introduces a lot of duplication in every place the widget is used. I hadn't considered the second approach, so that may be a reasonable fallback if the third solution is deemed inappropriate.

Comment: Annoyingly, it doesn't work when that control is then instantiated inside another control, the WrapWith part gets lost.